# Cannot open file "/tests/ExampleTest.php" Laravel5 using Windows10

Tags: windows, unit-testing, laravel-5

i am running phpunit testing in laravel5 on windows 10,and getting this error by running the following command.

```
Cannot open file "/tests/ExampleTest.php",
D:\wamp64\www\forum\vendor\bin>phpunit /tests/ ExampleTest.php
```

Can you please suggest me what could be the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its seems that "phpunit" is not installed globally,try run this command from cli  to install it globally and then you can use unit testing globally.

```
"composer global require phpunit/phpunit"
```